# SC StartService FAILED 1056 batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am getting

> [SC] StartService FAILED 1056 An Instance of this service is already running`

for `w3svc` when I try to start the service in a batch file using:

```
sc \\%server% query w3svc | find "STATE" | find "RUNNING"
sc \\%server% start w3svc
```

This only happens when I run the build after making a change.

For some reason it is saying that the service is running, when in fact, it is not.

Comment: When a service isn't running, it doesn't mean that you can start it. A service has other states, such as stopping, paused, start pending etc. _You're not checking any of these states_.

Comment: It is on stop_pending apparently. But, why would it show this only when I run new builds? Also, this only happens on one version of the builds I did even though code is identical.

Comment: Unfortunately there's little chance that we can determine that for you, without us also having the exact same environment. You will have to determine its state and only start it when it's state allows you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

These are the states. You are only checking if running or not. All but one will return Running.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245911.aspx

```
dwCurrentState 
The current state of the service. This member can be one of the following values. Value Meaning 
SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING The service continue is pending. 
SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING The service pause is pending. 
SERVICE_PAUSED The service is paused. 
SERVICE_RUNNING The service is running. 
SERVICE_START_PENDING The service is starting. 
SERVICE_STOP_PENDING The service is stopping. 
SERVICE_STOPPED The service is not running.
```

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
sc \\%server% query w3svc | findstr "STATE RUNNING" >nul 2>&1 || (
  sc \\%server% start w3svc
)
```

Comment: This eliminates the error message, but it does not actually start the service. For some reason the service just says that it is running, but in fact, it does not run.

Comment: @TalC what do you mean by _"For some reason the service just says that it is running"_ if you go to `services.msc` does it show it as running?

Comment: Exactly, it shows it is not running in services.msc

Comment: @TalC but when you run `sc \\%server% query w3svc | findstr "STATE RUNNING"` does it show running?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard it shows stop_pending right now, I assume the state may change at different times. Is there any way to force start? Also this is weird as it only happens when I run new builds on this specific build file(even though it is the same, just builds to different folders) .

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Nic3500 it does not answer the question unfortunately, it only removes the error message while not solving the underlying issue.